# Hexadecimal to binary

Tags: java, binary, hex, filereader

I am reading hexadecimal numbers and I convert them into binary numbers. It works just fine until I read 'fffffff8' hexadecimal, it through an exception.

This is the exception I keep getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "fffffff8"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at hexToDecimal.hex2decimal.main(hex2decimal.java:33)
```

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line;
    String toBinary;
    try {
        // myFile
        URL url = hex2decimal.class.getResource("gcc.trace");
        File file = new File(url.getPath());
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.length() == 15){
               //line example: s 0x1fffff50 1

                line = line.substring(4, line.length() -3);
            }
            else if (line.length() == 14){
            line = line.substring(4, line.length() -2);
            }

            toBinary = Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(line, 16));
            while (toBinary.length() < 32 ){
                toBinary = "0" +toBinary;
            }
            System.out.println(toBinary);
            stringBuffer.append(line);
            stringBuffer.append("\n");
        }
        fileReader.close();
        System.out.println("Contents of file:");
        System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: Hello ABD, Could you please provide more information, Understand from the Question that, it throws Exception only for fffffff8 which means it works fine for this pattern #AARRGGBB or it works only for #RRGGBB ?

Comment: `fffffff8` equates to `4294967288`, but `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is only `2147483647`, try using `Long.parseLong(line, 16)` instead

Answer (score 1):

The max value for Integer is

```
 public static final int   MAX_VALUE = 0x7fffffff
```

when you try to parse number which exceeds the max `NumberFormatException` will be thrown, **0xfffffff8 (4294967288) >  0x7fffffff (2147483647)**

try `Long.parseLong(line, 16)` which has max of `0x7fffffffffffffffL`